# Custom Flume Sink Deployment in Flume 1.6

Tags: java, flume, flume-ng

I am using Flume 1.6 and have a custom sink implementation. I have built a JAR file with all necessary dependencies and placed it under `<FLUME_DIR>/plugins.d/MySink/lib/MySink.jar`

As far as I can tell from reading the resources available, if I place my JAR file under the plugins.d directory the class path must be resolved automatically when I run `flume-ng`. However, I get the following exception stack saying that main class in my sink implementation cannot be loaded:

> org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Unable to load sink type: 
>       MySink, class: MySink

**QUESTION:** Am I supposed to make any further specific settings in a config file in Flume? Isn't it sufficient to place the JAR file under the directory structure, that is:

```
<FLUME_DIR>/plugins.d/MySink/lib/MySink.jar
```

Thanks....

**EXCEPTION TRACE:**

```
2016-01-21 10:52:51,500 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO -org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadChannels(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:200)] Created channel kafkaChnl2
2016-01-21 10:52:51,501 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.create(DefaultSourceFactory.java:41)] Creating instance of source httpSource, type http
2016-01-21 10:52:51,576 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.create(DefaultSinkFactory.java:42)] Creating instance of sink: myownsink, type: MySink
2016-01-21 10:52:51,576 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.getClass(DefaultSinkFactory.java:63)] Sink type MySink is a custom type
2016-01-21 10:52:51,578 (conf-file-poller-0) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.node.
PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.
run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:142)] 

Failed to load configuration data. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Unable to load sink type: 
MySink, class: MySink
at 
    org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.getClass(DefaultSinkFactory.java:71)
at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.create(DefaultSinkFactory.java:43)
at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSinks(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:410)
at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:98)
at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at  java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Schedul edThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MySink
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at   org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.getClass(DefaultSinkFactory.java:69)
```

Comment: Isn't there anyone in the flume community who can have comments on the above problem?

Comment: It looks I resolved the problem in two steps. First, I have noticed I did not indicated the fully qualified class name within my flume configuration (i.e. com.xyz.MySink). It was simply MySink in the conf file :)  Secondly, I have placed MySink.jar under <FLUME_DIR>/lib directory. Then, above exception is gone....

Comment: After all, it is still weird that placing the jar file under plugins.d directory does not work although it is specified in this way in the flume documentation. Please, provide any comment here on this matter.